# how to read config file which contains lua table

Tags: lua

I am new to lua. I have a query related to table reading from file.
I have a config file in lua table format:
example:

```
return {
  ["param1"] = {
      ["attribute"] = {
          ["myparam"] = 1,
      },
  ["param2"] = 1
}
```

How do i read this file and access my config file parameters ?

Comment: Config files that contain unchecked code are a bad idea.   Be careful with these

Comment: You forgot `},` to closing first "param1" table

Answer (score 3):

If you want to read the config file using another Lua script:

> configdata = require("configfile")

Note that 'require' can only load Lua-files.
Also, do NOT include the '.lua' extension when using 'require'.

Comment: Your "hard way" is utter crap. You read the file line-wise & re-concatenate (quadratically slow! just open the file and `:read"*a"` – you're not changing any of the content).  Then you `loadstring` the result (which is a function you can call as often as you like), but call that immediately and therefore wrap the inner code first to assign the actual code as a function to a global variable. `configData = loadfile "config.lua"` has the same effect as your 5 lines, without all the nonsense.

Comment: @nobody Your way of commenting is utter crap. You could aswell just advise me to use ':read"*a"' instead of io.lines without trying to insult me. Also, read the reason behind the "hard" mode before calling it stupid.

I learned Lua by book, not by internet. So my way of writing code may differ a lot from yours, but that doesn't mean that you should express your frustration this way.

This website is meant for learning, not for calling someone stupid for writing code differently.

But thx, I will use ':read"*a"' instead

Comment: (Side-branch:) IMHO calling "accidentally quadratic" code "utter crap" is adequate. You seem to be taking that personally, which was not the intended effect: sorry about that. To see how bad repeated concatenation is, try `local c = "" ; for i = 1, 1e6 do c=c.."." end` vs. `local t = {} ; for i = 1, 1e6 do t[i]="." end ; local c=table.concat(t)`. Both do the same job of concatenating 1M characters, but while the second one takes ~0.5s, the first one takes _over three minutes_! (See why I say that's crap?) So: when concatenating in a loop, accumulate into a table & `table.concat` at the end!

Comment: …(Or just avoid all the concatenations if possible – e.g. by reading all at once.) And I think I did see the purpose of your code (storing a function that you can call to get a copy of the config structure), which is what the rest of my first comment was about – `load` and `loadfile` already give you a function. `load("foo = function() return 23 end")()` and `foo = load("return 23")` do (essentially) the same thing. So again no need to wrap things, just use the function that `loadfile` gives you, assign it where you want, and then skip all the hassle of reading the file etc.

Comment: @nobody I understand. I'll use *:read"*a"* instead in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply `require` the config file in your application source.

```
local config = require "config"
```

Comment: `require` accepts a *module* name, not a *file* name.

Comment: @lhf ah yes. Had forgotten about that. Fixed.